# 2.81 Transparent Background Shadow Catcher

Tags: materials, shadows

I have a fairly simple setup in Blender 2.81a.

[image]

A model, light source, camera, and a simple plane beneath it. I am attempting to render an image which renders the plane as a transparent background, but also has the shadow of the model cast onto it. In prior versions of blender this was do-able simply by allowing shadow casting onto the object and then making the object transparent, but this seems insufficient now that I have updated.

I have tried Eevee, and Cycles, but neither worked the way I'd like.

Currently I am messing around with a Mix shader comprised of a Transparent BSDF and a Diffuse, but while setting the Fac to 0.1 gets a "close" result, it still brightens the background slightly (since my diffuse color is white), which ruins the effect that I'm going for.

Any help would be appreciated. I am still very much a beginner with Blender.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a "shadow catcher" option in the object visibility properties. It works only in cycles. Actually I don't know of a simple easy way to do it in Eevee.

[image]

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get home, thank you! Is there any changes I should make to my material? Will this work with a pure transparent plane?

Comment: As a matter of fact I think you should not use a transparent shader for this. In my picture the plane uses the default material so I guess a simple diffuse shader would work

Comment: The plane will render as a transparent background even without a transparent shader? Interesting... OK, very eager to try this.

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thank you sir!