# How can I integrate a 3D model in a photo?

Tags: rendering, light, lighting

If I have a photograph and I want, for example, to add a 3D model of a character so that it seems that it is standing there in the environment, how can I achieve it? At the same time, keeping the tones and lighting of the photograph, and if possible add shadow on the ground so that it really gives the feeling of standing there.

Comment: For the shadow do a search for shadow catcher.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164530/2-81-transparent-background-shadow-catcher